# Chrome vs Node - Why node is fetching slower than Chrome?

Tags: node.js, performance, google-chrome, http, axios

Comparing response time of **Node** to **Chrome**, node is slower. I'm making request to the same page; making two request, one from Node and the second one from Chrome console.

- **Chrome v**: Latest
- **Node v**: 12
- **OS**: Windows 64x

**Node:**

```
const fetch = require("node-fetch");

const url =
  "https://poshmark.com/search?query=t%20shirts&availability=sold_out&department=All";
(async () => {
  console.time("Load Time: ");
  await fetch(url);
  console.timeEnd("Load Time: ");
})();
```

**Chrome**:
Go to the url and then run this in console.

```
  (async () => {
    console.time("Load Time: ");
    var request = await fetch(location);
    console.timeEnd("Load Time: ");
})();
```

**Results:**

- Node: ~3.746s
- Chrome:1030.53515625ms

Is there anything that we can do to fix this?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Are you 100% sure `fetch()` has actually read the body of the response?  If you don't call `res.json()` or `res.text()` or something like that and waited for that to finish, then you haven't read the body of the response with `fetch()`, just received the headers.

Comment: My concern is related to the the actual request finish time no the response body. If you inspect this request in the network tab and move to the timing section, you'll be able to see the total time it took to finish the request.

Comment: The code you show for `fetch()` doesn't read the body of the data so it's not a fair comparison.  If you want to illustrate more complete code, then please show that.  We need to see exactly what you are comparing.

Comment: @jfriend00 - You're right, I've added a fetch vs node fetch comparison now and the code is almost the same for both but still getting different results.

Comment: What are you actually trying to measure?  The time to get headers?  Or the time to get the whole response?

Comment: Time to get the whole response is the goal. However, if we measure both and compare, Chrome is still twice as fast Node.

Comment: You aren't showing code that gets the whole response.  You are only showing code that gets the headers.  That's what I've been saying the whole time.  I cannot tell if you're comparing apples to apples or apples to oranges.  You could also have DNS differences with caching in some scenarios vs. fetching from DNS server.  I'll leave this to someone else since I'm apparently not helping.

Comment: Thanks for your help but the point I'm trying to make is a bit different. It doesn't matter if you include the whole response or just retrieve the headers, the Node side will be 50% slower than Chrome. Did you try to compare the results using my snippets?

Comment: Your chrome snippet is probably just loading the page from the browser cache.  And, you should be measuring the thing that actually matters.  If you need the whole response, you should be measuring the whole response.  To be meaningful, measurements like this have to be very thoughtfully done.

Comment: We're trying to compare the load times. If loading headers is taking 2 secs on Node, that should match with Chrome vice versa.

If they are not matching, we should at least know the reason. Caching is not the problem because I'm in Incognito Mode.

Measuring whole response is not important at this point.

Comment: Are you getting the same results?

Comment: Who says incognito mode doesn't use a browser memory cache?

Answer (score 0):

With this code in node.js that loads the whole response with two different libraries:

```
"use strict";

const got = require('got');
const fetch = require("node-fetch");


async function run1(silent) {
    let url = "https://poshmark.com/search?query=t%20shirts&availability=sold_out&department=All";
    url += `&random=${Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000000)}`;
    if (silent) {
        let {body} = await got(url);
    } else {
        console.time("Load Time Got");
        let {body} = await got(url);
        console.timeEnd("Load Time Got");
    }
}



async function run2(silent) {
    let url = "https://poshmark.com/search?query=t%20shirts&availability=sold_out&department=All";
    url += `&random=${Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000000)}`;
    if (silent) {
        let body = await fetch(url).then(res => res.text());
    } else {
        console.time("Load Time Fetch");
        let body = await fetch(url).then(res => res.text());
        console.timeEnd("Load Time Fetch");
    }
}

function delay(t) {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, t));
}

async function go() {
    await delay(1000);
    // one throw away run for each to make sure everything is fully initialized
    await run1(true);
    await run2(true);

    // let garbage collector settle down
    await delay(1000);

    await run1(false);
    await delay(1000);
    await run2(false);

}

go();
```

And, run four separate times, I get these results:

```
Load Time Got: : 967.574ms
Load Time Fetch: : 921.211ms

Load Time Got: 872.823ms
Load Time Fetch: 858.379ms

Load Time Got: 802.700ms
Load Time Fetch: 930.276ms

Load Time Got: 819.646ms
Load Time Fetch: 966.878ms
```

So, I'm not seeing multiple second responses here.  Note, I'm generating a unique query parameter for each URL to attempt to defeat any caching anywhere.

Using a similar randomized URL in similar code in the browser console that loads the whole response body, I get runs of 748.2ms, 647.9ms, 738.2ms.

Comment: @rehan - I'm curious why no response?  What do you think about this?

Comment: I'll need try the same on my side and then I can share my results to compare. Thanks for your efforts.

Comment: I'm getting the same results -- ~900 ms on Chrome and ~2 secs on Node JS.

Comment: @Rehan - Well, not reproducible here so I don't know what to say.  FYI, I'm running node v12.13.1 on Windows 10.

Comment: I've tried both, the latest and the version you have installed but sill the there's a delay on the node side.

Comment: Thanks for the help.